# Token Fields not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried an example provided on bootstrap, but not getting success in it.

can anyone help me in solving and understanding it.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="red,green,blue" />
```

JS

```
$('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
  autocomplete: {
    source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
    delay: 100
  },
  showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
})
```

Comment: You will need to explain the issue you are facing, we can't guess it for you + you need to copy your code in the question itself...

Comment: the problem in you case is that you are not including bootstrap-tokenfield.js file.

Comment: @Kartikeya thankyou for your rep if you can only write it in as answer I will rep your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you are not including `bootstrap-tokenfield.js` file which is required for `tokenfield` to work, just download it and give reference of `js` file on your page.